# Progressbar not showing while doing calculation

Tags: c#

I have created a windows form in C#.
in this form I have a "Calculation Button" and a ProgressBar

When I click the Calculation button, a user control is generted and in this user control some caculation are made. I want the progressbar to show the progress of the caculation made in the usercontrol.

in the Main Form I havae this code:

```
public Main()
{
   InitializaComponent()
}
private void Btn_PVT_Validar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       progressbar.Visible = true;
       progressbar.Maximum=115;
       M_Results m_Results = new M_Results()
       m_Results.Visible = true;
}
```

in the userControl i have this:

```
public Results()
{
   InitializaComponent()
}
 private void Results_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        Control parent = this.Parent as Control;
        pbar = parent.Controls["progressbar"] as radProgressBar;
        dens();
 }
private void dens()
{
 //loop calculattion and other stuffs and in each loop i have this:
 pbar.value1=pbar.value1+2;
}
```

the progressabar progress is not being shown, just when everything finish, the progressbar appears and is full.

what should I do?

Thanks Carlos

Comment: The simplest way would be to use a background worker that reports progress, you could also run dens() as a task - google them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Application.DoEvents()` evrytime you change progressbar value:

```
private void dens()
{
   pbar.value1=pbar.value1+2;
   Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Comment: there are much better ways of doing this, please see my comment above.

Comment: @Kevin I know that and I totally agree with you, but in this case I got the implication that the OP is bothered that updating progressbar.value won't take effect and a simple way to solve that, of course running it in another thread will be more efficient especially if the task loop takes long. but I don't think its not what the OP wants.

Comment: I know that the doevents() should be avoided, but that solution work worked for me... the best way to do it is using backgroudworker but Im basic coder and I dont know yet how to implement that.

Comment: @calarez that is exactly why I suggested this. actually from your question i got that. so my answer was what you were looking for?

Comment: yes... but I have one problem.. some chart that are being generated in the Dens() are show with the progressbar update algo :(

Comment: @calarez for this you must implement it in another thread, and as Kevin said, background worker would be easiest way to do it.